# What is [assembly: Dependency()] in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am new to Xamarin. I was following a tutorial and in that

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof())]
```

was used. I didn't understand what is the function of this line of code. 
Kindly explain it's function.

The following is the code.

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(SQLiteAndroid))]

namespace XamTestThree.Droid.Data {
    public class SQLiteAndroid :ISQLite{
        public SQLiteAndroid() { }
        public SQLite.SQLiteConnection GetConnection()
        {
            var sqlLiteFileName = "TestDB.db3";
            string documentPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            var path = Path.Combine(documentPath, sqlLiteFileName);
            var conn = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(path);
            return conn; 

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**This is called Registration.**

The platform implementations must be registered with the `DependencyService`, so that `Xamarin.Forms` can locate them at runtime.

This is typically performed with the `DependencyAttribute`, *which indicates that the specified type provides an implementation of the `interface`.*

For more information visit [DependencyServices - Microsoft docs.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction)

Answer (score 1):

It's a dependency attribute.

The **DependencyAttribute** can be used to register a platform implementation with the **DependencyService**. The attribute indicates that the specified type provides a concrete implementation of the interface.

The following example shows using the DependencyAttribute to register the iOS implementation of the IDeviceOrientationService interface:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(DeviceOrientationService))]
namespace DependencyServiceDemos.iOS
{
    public class DeviceOrientationService : IDeviceOrientationService
    {
        public DeviceOrientation GetOrientation()
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

For further documentation checkout the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/registration-and-resolution)

Answer (score 0):

In my case this line is showing this error:

```
**cannot convert from 'System.Type' to 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.LoadHint'**
`[assembly: DefaultDependency(typeof(SQLite_Android))]`
```